# How to draw Maximum inscribed cylinder

Tags: matlab

suppose we know "N" number points on cylinder surface then how to find out the Maximum inscribed cylinder i.e radius and center line of cylinder

Comment: Do you mean drawing or finding? Those are two separate things.

Comment: What about using `lsqnonlin` to find the parameters which best fit your data?

Comment: Is the cylinder oriented in the axes of the coordinate system or can it be in any angle?

Comment: @Lanting both the things i want

Comment: @jolo thank you for your suggestion but i want maximum inscribed cylinder not least fit cylinder

Comment: @hbaderts cylinder axis is parallel to any one of the axis.
e.g cylinder is resting on XY plane and axis is parallel to Z axis.

Comment: @suds You wrote that your points lie on a cylinder surface - thus I still think model fitting your data should work. In this case the "maximum inscribed cylinder" *is* the "least fit cylinder".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's create the `n` points of the cylinder. Is use a cylinder with `h=4` and `r=1` in this example. The volume of the cylinder is [image: V=2 pi r^2 h] which is in this case [image: 25.1327]

```
n = 1000;
h = 4;
r = 1;

r1 = r*rand(n/4,1);
theta1 = 2*pi*rand(n/4,1);
h1 = zeros(n/4,1);
r2 = r*rand(n/4,1);
theta2 = 2*pi*rand(n/4,1);
h2 = h.*ones(n/4,1);
r3 = r.*ones(n/2,1);
theta3 = 2*pi*rand(n/2,1);
h3 = h.*rand(n/2,1);
x = [ r1.*sin(theta1), r1.*cos(theta1), h1 ; ...    % bottom area
      r2.*sin(theta2), r2.*cos(theta2), h2 ; ...    % top area
      r3.*sin(theta3), r3.*cos(theta3), h3 ];       % side area
```

[image: Cylinder]

We can estimate `r` and `h` by finding the minimum and maximum values in each dimension

```
x1 = max(x(:,1)) - min(x(:,1));
x2 = max(x(:,2)) - min(x(:,2));
x3 = max(x(:,3)) - min(x(:,3));
```

To get the radius, we must find the two dimensions which match best. We can estimate the radius by taking the mean of these. As we subtract the min value from the max we have the diameter, so we need to divide by 2 to get the radius.

```
d = [abs(x2-x1), abs(x3-x2), abs(x3-x1)];
c = find(d==min(d));
if c==1
    rhat = mean([x1,x2]) ./ 2;
    hhat = x3;
elseif c==2
    rhat = mean([x2,x3]) ./ 2;
    hhat = x1;
else
    rhat = mean([x1,x3]) ./ 2;
    hhat = x2;
end
```

Now we can easily calculate the estimated volume

```
Vhat = 2 * pi * rhat^2 * hhat

Vhat = 
     25.1318
```

which is almost identical to the calculated result. Of course this only works if the cylinder is oriented in the axes of the coordinate system, but according to a comment this is the case.